# Как изменить значение в столбце одной таблицы при добавлении записи во вторую?

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос:

```
INSERT INTO five_pair (p_id, amount, description, currency)
SELECT af_id, 
       SUM(COALESCE(amount_value,0))*0.1, 
       CONCAT('Бонус за: ', GROUP_CONCAT(o.uid ORDER BY o.uid ASC)),
       'RUB'
FROM ( SELECT arur.af_id,
              arur.r_w_uid, 
              @row_num := CASE WHEN @row_num_val = af_id                
                               THEN @row_num+1
                               WHEN (@row_num_val := af_id) IS NOT NULL 
                               THEN 1
                               END   pair_flag,
              @lag_r_w_uid :=  CASE WHEN (@row_num_val = af_id) AND @row_num mod 2 = 1 
                                    THEN r_w_uid
                                    ELSE @lag_r_w_uid
                                    END r_w_uid_1     
       FROM arur, 
            u_af, 
            ( SELECT @row_num := null, @row_num_val := null, @lag_r_w_uid := null) AS x
       WHERE u_af.id = arur.af_id 
       ORDER BY af_id, r_w_uid) t1  
JOIN orders o ON (o.uid IN (t1.r_w_uid,t1.r_w_uid_1) AND o.status = 'Completed' AND o.used = '0')
WHERE pair_flag mod 2 = 0
GROUP BY af_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r_w_uid) =  4
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить значение в столбце `used` таблицы `orders` с 0 на 1 у тех `orders`.`uid` которые попадают в результаты запроса?

Пробовала так:

```
update orders
 set used = 1
 where used = 0
     and FIND_IN_SET(uid, (select substr(description, 11) from five_pair where (тут различные условия) )) >0
```

Но это не работает.

Таблицы с кодом можно посмотреть по этой ссылке: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a5e2a01370c95acbe5ca8531139b2716)

Помогите, пожалуйста. 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: *изменить значение в столбце одной таблицы при добавлении записи во вторую?* В MySQL - только триггером.

Comment: @Akina, А триггер к чему цеплять? Т.е. если добавилась запись в таблицу `five_pair`, то изменить значения `orders`.`used` с 0 на 1 у каких `uid`? Как это узнать?

Comment: *у каких uid? Как это узнать?* Запрос есть? есть... вот с его помощью и узнать. Только дополнительно фильтрануть из результата записи, у которых  в этом поле уже единица...

Comment: @Akina Спасибо, за то что Вы всегда со мной) Сама я не справляюсь, мозг не хочет работать, а надо. Помогите, пожалуйста, победить эту проблему с изменением значения.